# ActiveAdmin how to get sum from column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a situation where I'd like to get the sum of one column and display it

e.g in activeadmin

```
ActiveAdmin.register Expense do    
   index do       

    column :amount 
    column :details
    column :created_at

    default_actions
  end         
end
```

I need to sum the `amount` column and show it. Also I can't figure out where to show the `Total Sum`, maybe the sidebar?
If the results are filtered then the sum has to change accordingly to results shown.

Answer (score 8):

You can avoid having to count up with a running total, by simply accessing the underlying `collection` which will take into account currently applied filters/scopes, and use `reduce(:+)` to perform the sum:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Expense do    
   index do       
    column :amount 
    column :details
    column :created_at

    default_actions

    div class: "panel" do
      h3 "Total amount: #{collection.pluck(:amount).reduce(:+)}"
    end
  end         
end
```

Comment: A bit simple code is: `collection.pluck(:amount).sum`

Answer (score 3):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Expense do    
  amount = 0
  index do       

  column :amount 
  column :details
  column :created_at
  column("sub amount") {|resource| amount = amount + resource.amount}
  default_actions
  div :class => "panel" do
    h3 "Total: #{amount}"
  end
 end         
end
```

Comment: This solution only totals the resources shown on the page, not all resources from the filter combined.

Comment: yes, I confirm. this has not much to do with the answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and couldn't find the answer, so after playing around a bit, I came up with this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Expense do
  index do

    column :amount
    column :details
    column :created_at

    default_actions

    div :class => "panel" do
      h3 "Total: #{Expense.search(params[:q]).result.sum(:amount)}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to use the code that was mention above with "amount=0" above the "index do", when I refresh the admin page the value get increase. This solved my problem.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Expense do    

  index do       
    amount = 0
    column :amount 
    column :details
    column :created_at
    column("sub amount") {|resource| amount = amount + resource.amount}
    default_actions
    div :class => "panel" do
      h3 "Total: #{amount}"
    end
  end         
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to see the amount only on the panel without the column ("sub amount") as do this code:

```
   ActiveAdmin.register Expense do    

    index do       
      amount = 0
      column :amount 
      column :details
      column :created_at
      registers.each {|resource| amount += resource.amount}
      default_actions
     div :class => "panel" do
       h3 "Total: #{amount}"
     end
   end         
 end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Expense do    

  index do       
    sum = 0
    column "Amount" do |expense|
      sum += expense.amount 
      expense.amount
    end
    column :details
    column :created_at
    default_actions
    div :class => "panel" do
      h3 "Total: #{sum}"
    end
  end         
end
```